Magento stuck on DB Access denied
I have configured maria db Master and Slave with replication enabled on both
it works great

Master IP is 192.168.5.129
Slave IP is 192.168.5.130

I have configured a load balancer and failover using haproxy on seperate server 192.168.5.131
all has debian latest version
now here comes the problem
I am able to downlaod the magento using the keys I have
Magento Error
Now the thing is on the same server i am able to connect with the same DB and password here is the screen shoot
mysql connection
What am i missing here
the magento DB is there, user has permission, i can connect with the DB as shown
it fails to install
the community version is latest one using the command
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento

Manually connected with DB thast fine
from load balacner it also fine
but from megento setup it fials
